# XSL/FO value substitution

Tags: xml, pdf, xslt

apologies if this is basic but Ive just picked up this issue in need of a quick fix.

We are generating a pdf from an xml form and need to do some substitution of values to display in the pdf.

Section of the xml looks like this

```
<c_child>
        <c_child_status/>
        <c_child_id>400044</c_child_id>
        <c_dob>2012-09-19</c_dob>
        <c_gender>M</c_gender>
        <c_forename>fred</c_forename>
        <c_surname>bloggs</c_surname>
    </c_child>
```

In current xsl/fo it uses the following to insert the gender value

```
<fo:table-cell border-style="inset" border-width="1pt" padding="2pt" background-repeat="repeat" display-align="center">
        <fo:block>
            <xsl:value-of select="//c_child/c_child_id"/>
        </fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
```

What I need to do is test the gender value, if its M I want to insert MALE, F then insert FEMALE into the final PDF.

Ive had a play with `xsl:if` test etc but while the XSL is considered valid its not doing the conversion.

Any help appreciated

Redbyte

Comment: The `xsl:value-of` is selecting `c_child_id` instead of `c_gender`. Is that because the wrong `fo:table-cell` was copied/pasted?

Comment: My apolgies Daniel, Ive copied the wrong section of the FO file

Comment: No problem that's what it looked like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using XSLT 2.0, you can put an `if` statement directly in the select...

```
<xsl:value-of select="if (//c_child/c_gender = 'M') then 'MALE' else 'FEMALE'"/>
```

If you're using XSLT 1.0 what I would do is replace the `xsl:value-of` with an `xsl:apply-templates` and add templates to handle `c_gender/text()`...

**Replacement `xsl:apply-templates`**

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="//c_child/c_gender"/>
```

**New `xsl:template`'s**

```
<xsl:template match="c_gender[.='M']/text()">
    <xsl:text>MALE</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="c_gender[.='F']/text()">
    <xsl:text>FEMALE</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

It's verbose, but is easy to manage imo. You could also use an `xsl:choose` instead of two separate templates. The `xsl:choose` could be in a separate template or directly in the `fo:table-cell` (replacing the `xsl:value-of`)...

```
<xsl:template match="c_gender/text()">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test=".='M'">
            <xsl:text>MALE</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:text>FEMALE</xsl:text>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Many thaks for this, Il give it a try. Not sure what the XSL being used is. Is that something I define at the top?                                                                                                                                                                                                                     <?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

Comment: @Redbyte - Yes the `version="1.0"` means the stylesheet is an XSLT 1.0 stylesheet. It's important to note though that even if it was set to 2.0, you would need to be using a 2.0 compliant processor to use any 2.0 functionality.

Comment: Thanks for your help Daniel!